# 2D tracking: problematic rotation stabilisation

Tags: workflow, tracking, video

Using **Blender 2.70** to stabilise moving shots.

The shot in question has extended duration and the camera moved around a lot, but the image is fairly stable. Thus we need to get rid of small bumps, and a constant slight tilting.

Obviously, this is a tricky basic situation, because there is *no single* trackable feature present during the whole duration of the shot. For the vertical and horizontal stabilisation, tracking several features and "fading out" using the track weight did the trick and gave me surprisingly good results.

But I couldn't find out how to get rotation tracking to work. As far as I can see, I can only add a single track. As soon as I do so, the image is heavily rotated, sometimes even upside down. Also, the result is not stable and changes noticeable when during the shot, additional tracks start contributing or go away.

When I use a feature which is present more or less at the beginning of the shot, and when I additionally clip all other tracks present at this point to start at exactly the same frame, then I get an initially stable rotation, but this situation deteriorates as the shot goes on.

Question: what are the known approaches how to deal with this situation? Is this even possible right now? Existing add-ons? Coding up something myself would also be an option but I don't want to waste time on re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: after looking in the source code, I don't wonder anymore why I'm running into problems when using that in practice. Problems can be solved though

Comment: currently attempting to get my reworked version to be accepted into official blender...

Comment: Would splitting up your footage into smaller strips help where you just stabalize each strip on its own and blend it together again afterwards?

Comment: not, that would not help, since it is very hard to match the strips manually at the joint point, without creating a visual jerk.

Anyway, I wrote an extension for Blender, which somehow does the job. Just it was not yet accepted into official blender. Seems no one has time to do the review. See https://developer.blender.org/D583